# How can I create an usable partition with unallocated space?

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, gparted, 21.04, disk-management

So I have an unallocated space in one of my disks, and I want to use it in order to storage my Downloads, I want to know first how can I make this space an usable space, and second, how can I move my Downloads folder there (this is easy on windows but I don't know how to do this here), thanks in advice, I made a capture:
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: I'm not sure, I have ubuntu installed in another different disk (/dev/sdb), I want to use this unallocated space from another disk to save files.

Comment: Since over 2TiB is this gpt partitioned. You can create a new partition and mount it in your Linux install. If gpt, you can just create new partition(s).  You can use gparted if you want ext4 Linux only partition. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You need to create a file system in order to use the space.**

You can use the "**Disks**" application to do format the partition and create a file system:

- Open the "**Disks**" application (`gnome-disk-utility`).
- In the left column, select the physical disk where the partition is located.  Then, on the right, select the unallocated space that you want to format.
- Just below the graphical representation of the partitions on the drive, click the `+` icon that says "*Create partition in unallocated space*"
- Click "*Next*" if you want to use all of the unallocated space.  Otherwise, adjust the size of the new partition before clicking "*Next*"
- Give the new partition a "*Volume Name*", and choose the type of file system you would like to use.  If you are going to use the partition for Ubuntu only, select "*Internal disk for use with Linux systems only (Ext4)*".
- Click "*Create*" to create the new partition.

Comment: It worked with disk, I tried to do with gparted but it said that it will remove all the files on the device. With disk I didn't have this problem and only formated the unallocated space, thank you.

Comment: I am getting error g-dbus-error-quark, 4 . I am doing this on my internal disk where i also have ubuntu (i only have one disk). What else can i do?

Comment: I see that your question has been answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1415285)