# Can't create partition from free space in internal drive ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, gparted, gnome-disk-utility

I have installed ubuntu in a 3TB disk and now it seems like the biggest part of it is lost.
When opening disks i see all the partitions and some free space. [image]
When i click the setting button all options are black and i can't click anything like formatting the partition. This is the only disk i have in my computer right now because i installed ubuntu from a usb directly to this disk.

SO when i tried to click the "+" button and create partition even with 2tb i am getting this error:

[image]

So as you see the whole application crashes and i am forced to close it.

I have also tried gparted but this gives this error:
[image]

And then the app crashes again...

I have looked all the related questions in this forum and also in others so please don't send me any of those and please don't flag it as a duplicate...

Yes i have also tried with command line but it didn't work and what happened was crashed the whole os and i lost everything and boot the os from scratch again.

Answer (score 4):

Your disk has an MBR partition table. This table has a limitation.

Maximum partition size is 2 TB. And total disk space available is also 2 TB.

You need to reformat the disk using GPT.

Comment: First of all this is not an answer. Anyway thanks for taking time to tell this but i have already tried creating smaller partitions and it didn't work

Comment: It is the answer. MBR has a 2TB limit, really all partitions. MBR was designed in the early 1980s when MB was large, GB was unheard of. You have to use gpt with any drive over 2TB and really should use gpt now for all drives. Conversion to gpt normally erases entire drive, so have good backups. You can convert but UUIDs will all change so fstab & grub at minimum have to be updated. https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Partitioning#Choosing_between_GPT_and_MBR

Comment: @YourHelper technically, this *is* the answer to why you're failing here. the limitation is your system is formatted with a MBR partition table.  The **maximum total disk space** usable by an MBR partition table, across all partitions, is 2TB.  You cannot use more than 2TB in this partition table format.  Your drive will need to be reformated with a GPT partition table that can use more than 2TB of disk space.  You may be better off doing a reinstall and a custom format of the disk with a GPT partition table.